# Write a module to replace jquery with another js library

Tags: javascript

jQuery is great. But sometimes it's not exactly what I want. What would it take to write a module that could enitrely replace jquery with something like mootools or closure? Would this even be possible without hacking core modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically you could use [`hook_js_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7) to remove all traces of jQuery (and any JS files that rely on jQuery) from the page build, and [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) to add your replacement library/code.

Bear in mind that you would have to re-implement a *lot* of system/contributed javascript in your library of choice to maintain the same UI experience for your admins/users.

Also remember you'll lose access to jQuery UI so none of those widgets will be available until you provide an alternative in your new library.

All in all, it would be a lot of work to do this.

Comment: So suppose I just want to replace it for the user facing front end and not the admin portion. I would just have to ensure that I either replace jquery dependencies in user facing modules or avoid modules that use jquery altogether (which might be tough since I'm guessing many of the core modules require it ...)?

Comment: To change it just for the front end would be a lot less problematic (most of the core jQuery code is for the admin section; although not all). In `hook_js_alter()` you could simply test that the current path begins with 'admin' and only remove jQuery (and add your new library) if it isn't

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove jQuery, but using other JavaScript libraries in parallel is not a problem.

You can add the library, and your custom JavaScript code with `drupal_add_js()`.

Comment: There is also [drupal_add_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7).